# Automatic class type inferences based off properties

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege

If i have four classes: Library, Function, Display and Information.

And two properties: Requires and Provides.
Where the range of both properties is the class: Information.

How do i use protege to say that:

- If an object both Requires and Provides Information then it is an
  instance of the class Function.
- If an object only Requires Information then it is an instance of the
  class Display.
- If an object only Provides Information then it is an instance of the
  class Library.

Comment: 1) that's similar to your previous question. You need a complex subclass (in Manchester Syntax here): `(Requires some Thing) and (Provides some Thing) SubClassOf: Function`. In Protege you have to use this tab to add such an axiom: https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege4Views#General_class_axioms

Comment: 2) and 3) are out of scope for standard OWL reasoning as in OWL there is the Open World Assumption.

Comment: @UninformedUser I've set it up as suggested and now have two superclasses (Requires something) and (Provides something). of which they are the domain of the properties (Requires) and (Provides) respectively. I also have the class (Function) which is a subclass of (requires something) and (provides something) such that if a class is in both superclasses it is automatically a function. I also wish to have a subclass of (requires something) called (Display) that an object becomes an instance of if it is an instance of the class (requires something) but not of class (function). Is this possible?

Comment: I know what you did now ... why the domain axioms? Also, why is `Function` a subclass of `(requires something) and (provides something) ` - as I said before, this is the wrong direction. In my first comment I've show how to write the axiom.

Comment: and no, again, Open World Assumption holds in OWL, negation does not help. having `( (p some A) and (not B) ) SubClassOf: C` won't make an individual `x` with `p(x, y), A(y)` being of type `C` - again, please read what Open World Assumption means and why it matters here